# Is there a built-in MySQL server in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm coding a Java application that needs a database. But the user of that app usually doesn't have a local MySQL server installation. An online MySQL server is not an option. So I'm looking for a solution to install a MySQL server with Java or use a built-in server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Java does not have a mysql database  server built-in, you need to install mysql server on the machine/server.

Comment: Install Xampp (my pref). Local machine/server for MySQL database

Comment: in memory db you can use `hsql` or `h2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an in-memory/file based database such as `H2`, `HSQL` or `SQLite` instead. If you really need `MySQL` (you probably don't), you'll need to have your users install it.

Comment: Thanks. I will use a SQLite database.